# Default phpMyAdmin Login Credentials

Tags: phpmyadmin, logins, password

I downloaded and installed phpMyAdmin 4.8.5 on my windows. Upon opening it in the browser, it immediately asks for a Username and Password. I tried to submit `root` for username while leaving the password black. I even try `password` as password. Unluckily, both didn't work by default.

So I checked the web and I saw [this from stackoverlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818358/phpmyadmin-default-login-password). Unfortunately, all of the given answers did not work for me and hello no, the thread is already closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I did

1. Open phpmyadmin directory
2. You will see `config.sample.inc` php file
3. Clone it, but remove the `sample` from the title
4. After cloning, open the file `config.inc` and look for `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;`
5. Set it to `true`

By doing this, we are allowing the phpMyAdmin to submit an empty password.

Now, try `root` as a username and leave the password blank.

Hope this will work for you as well.

Comment: It says
/* Uncomment the following to enable logging in to passwordless accounts,
 * after taking note of the associated security risks. */

Answer (score 0):

By default, root is not allowed to login with password but with an auth_socket plugin.

The solution is to change that behavior by running next command in mysql (login to mysql first)

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH caching_sha2_password BY 'password';
```

[Securing phpMyAdmin on Ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-20-04) provides additional details.

Answer (score -1):

Username: Root
Password: Empty- Nothing to write, Click Enter

Comment: Thank you for giving time to answer, but it is clear on the post that I already tried the solution you gave even before you post it.

Answer (score -1):

It might be that you have not installed all Visual C++ Packages.The package cab be found on below link.
http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/?lang=en&prerequis=afficher